# Google OrgChart line issue

Tags: treeview, orgchart, organizational-chart, google-visualization

I am trying to use Google OrgChart but somehow on some cases the line connection between node is not horizontally centered. Is there any workaround for this? Thank you.

[image: The line is not horizontally aligned]<sup>*The line is not horizontally aligned.*</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the issue with this. It is the obsolete Bootstrap version that causing this to happen. Thank you.